# Absolute formula

Tags: set-theory, model-theory

I'm trying to study the model of Set Theory and I have a problem. If I know that a formula is absolute for a class, could I infer that the formula is true in my class? Namely, I'm trying to prove in $ZF^{-}$ (ZF without the axiom of foundation) that $(V_\omega,\epsilon) \vDash ZF-Inf+ \neg Inf$. I know that union, pairing,.. are $\Delta_0$ formulas that for transitive class are absolute. Can i directly conclude for the previous observation that these axioms are satisfies in $(V_\omega,\epsilon)$? Or I have to prove it in another way?

Comment: As I know, the formula $z=\{x,y\}$ is $\Delta_0$ so it is absolute. But the axiom of pairing itself is *not* $\Delta_0$. You must assure that $\{x,y\}$ is an element of $V_\omega$, then since $\{x,y\}^{V_\omega}=\{x,y\}$ (because the formula $z=\{x,y\}$ is $\Delta_0$ so it is absolute), $V_\omega$ satisfy pairing axiom.

Comment: @tetori ok. thank you. Now my problem is how to guarantee that $\{x,y \}$ belongs to $V_{\omega}$. It seems trivial but it isn't...any advice?

Comment: If $x,y\in V_\omega$ then $x,y\in V_n$ for some $n<\omega$. Since $V_{n+1}=\mathcal{P}(V_n)$, we get $\{x,y\}\in V_{n+1}$ so $\{x,y\}\in V_\omega$.

Comment: @tetori thank you very much...I have another question, i promise the last. I'm trying to prove the axiom of union but my problem is that i don't know how to prove that $Ux \in V_{\omega}$. I have tried via rank and via definition but nothing. Some help??

Comment: If $x\in V_\omega$ then $x\in V_n$ for some $n\ge 2$, therefore $x\subset V_{n-1}$ (why?) so if $z\in x$ then $z\in V_{n-1}$, which imply $z\subset V_{n-2}$. Therefore, $\bigcup x = \bigcup_{z\in x} z\subset V_{n-2}$ so $\bigcup x\in V_{n-1}$.

Comment: There is nothing that one would call "the model of Set Theory". You may study set theory, or models of set theory, or the set theoretic universe, or a specific model of a specific fragment of set theory, but not "the model of Set Theory".

Comment: By the way, the answer to the question is "no" (although it's probably not the question you meant to ask.)  If a formula $\varphi$ is absolute to $V_\omega$ it doesn't follow that it's true in $V_\omega$.  If $\varphi$ is absolute to $V_\omega$ then so is $\neg \varphi$, but they can't both be true in $V_\omega$.  Also the formula $\bot$ is absolute to every transitive class, but (by definition) false in every model.  What you can say is that if $\varphi$ is absolute to $V_\omega$ and is also _true_, then it is true in $V_\omega$ (a straightforward consequence of the definition of "absolute".)

Comment: @TrevorWilson You are right! thank you for your precious remark!